# Sudo over SSH mixes up password tty and stdin

Tags: ssh, sudo

Setup:

- Local *nix machine with a SQL script `script.sql` (Postgres).
- Remote machine `remote` (Debian 7) with Postgres.

  - I can SSH in as `some_user`, who is a sudoer.
  - Anything with Postgres needs to be done as `postgres` user.
  - The server only listens on `localhost:5432`.

**How do I execute `script.sql` on `remote` without copying it there first?**

This works well:

```
ssh -t some_user@remote 'sudo -u postgres psql -c "COMMANDS FOO BAR"'
```

The `-t` flag means that `sudo` will ask for `some_user`'s password correctly on the local terminal.

One thing remains, to be able to pipe `script.sql` to `psql`. This does not work:

```
ssh -t some_user@remote 'sudo -u postgres psql' < script.sql
```

It fails with the message:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

---

### Edit: simplified example

Postgres and `psql` don't seem to figure much in the problem. The following code has the same issues:

```
ssh some_user@remote xargs sudo ls < input_file
```

The problem seems to be: we need to send 2 inputs to `sudo`, both the password using a tty, and the `stdin` to pass to `ls`.

### Edit: even simpler

```
ssh localhost xargs sudo ls < input_file
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Adding `-t` does not work:

```
$ ssh -t localhost xargs sudo ls < input_file
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Adding another `-t` does not work either:

```
$ ssh -t -t localhost xargs sudo ls < input_file
<content of input_file>
<waiting on a prompt>
```

Comment: sorry, can't reproduce your error with the simplified example.  This only fails when you add the -t switch.  Quit slapping yourself with a stick and claiming you're in pain.  The only thing I can think of is to add -t -t and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Even more simplified example added. -t -t does not work.

Comment: sorry, still can't reproduce your problem, even with the simplest example.  I'm a PG guy, and I think I answered your question from that point of view.  I hope a shell guy chimes in here and figures out your configuration.

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -T some_user@remote "sudo -u postgres psql -f-" < script.sql
```

"-f-" will read the script from STDIN.  Just redirect the file in there, and there you go.

Don't bother with -t option to ssh, you don't need a full terminal for this.

Comment: Does not work, returns error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Comment: If you absolutely must use the -t option (don't know why), then at least invoke it without the pseudo-terminal.  Answer edited.

Comment: Your answer currently combines `-t` and `-T`: "Force pseudo-tty allocation" and "Disable pseudo-tty allocation".

Comment: @vektor  well, that was silly, only meant -T.  edited

Comment: Sorry, still not working. I've added a simplified example for everyone to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -T ${user}@${ip} sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive postgres psql -f- < test.sql
```

Use `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` for resolve `no tty present` or equivalent of your distribution.

Comment: Tried your approach, I am still getting `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.